# What sets IsFaulted to false?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I understand that IsFaulted is property that can only be used with Get and what its use is for but I'm having trouble understanding if and when it is ever changed from true to false. Most sites I see online discuss what it is used for and maybe having a check for it but I don't see them ever changing it intentionally or through some kind of work around.

Comment: It only has a `get` accessor and so is only set internally - you can't change it externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about [`Task.IsFaulted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It gets changed to `true` if there is an unhanded exception during the tasks' execution. Its state depends on the state flags set internally.

You can see from code of `IsFaulted` that there is no setter:

```
public bool IsFaulted 
{ 
    get
    { 
        // Faulted is "king" -- if that bit is present (regardless of other bits), we are faulted.
        return ((m_stateFlags & TASK_STATE_FAULTED) != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and was just wondering if there was a way to track when it got set to true or if I could set it myself. I'm working with a modified version of http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm and the part were it checks if Isfaulted is false is always coming back true.

Comment: Your modifications probably introduced a behavior that throws an exception. You can wrap your task code with a `try { ... } catch { ... }` block (put it *in* the task, not around the code creating it) and you'll see when it happens. If you handle the exception your task won't be Faulted, otherwise you can rethrow if you want it to be faulted. A task cannot be "unfaulted".

Comment: How would that be done to catch the exception then? If you look at the link it has it checking IsFaulted first thing then throwing an exception if it fails. That gives a generic error that I cant do much with. Taking that if statement and the throw out and it doesn't catch an error or complete what I need it to do.

Comment: Oh I see... the original faulted task is not yours. Sorry I didn't notice that. Then check `Task.Exception` (which is an `AggregateException` so you'll have to check what it contains) to see what happened with `ReadAsMultipartAsync` to make it faulted.

Comment: That did it. I got a more specific exception that I can now spend the rest of the day trying to chase down.

Answer (score 0):

It is set when the task is first completed.  If you want to execute some code when the task completes (or have it run immediately if the task has already completed) you can call `ContinueWith` on the `Task`.  You will know that `IsFaulted` will be set at that point.

As for what sets it, that depends entirely on what is generating the task.  The whole point of using tasks is that, as a consumer of a `Task`, you don't need to know or care about how it's set.  Just add your continuation and you can clearly see if the task completed successfully or not.

If you're given another task you shouldn't be trying to find some way of marking it as faulted, but what you *can* do is provide a new task that is based on another task, but that alters its result in some way.  Usually you would use `ContinueWith` to do this.  You could, for example, write a continuation for a task that, if the result is some value that you consider invalid, throw an exception, else just return the result.  Then whoever you pass that `Task` to will be able to see what you want them to see.